# How to reload a div with different parameters?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some tabs. On selection of each tab, a particular div should get initialized with some particular values of parameters corresponding to each tab and reload. How can it be done?

Here are the tabs:

```
<div ng-controller="visCtrl as ctrl" class="container col-sm-12"> 
    <div class="bs-example">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active:ctrl.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click="ctrl.setTab(1)">Crime</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:ctrl.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click="ctrl.setTab(2)">Accidents</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <!-- i want the $scope.districts to be changed and the following select show the corresponding options -->
        District:<select ng-model="selectedDistrict" ng-options="item as item for item in districts | orderBy:'toString()' " ></select>
        <!-- A LOT OF SIMILAR CODE WHICH WILL BE USING OTHER UPDATED PARAMETERS -->
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Show the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case you should use `ng-route` that would be more appropriate to use, Only you need to change your URL in navigation bar on basis of url change you need to load template with controller which you has specified in `$routeProvider` configuration

```
<div ng-controller="visCtrl as ctrl" class="container col-sm-12"> 
    <div class="bs-example">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active:ctrl.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click="ctrl.setTab(1)" ng-href="/tab/1">Crime</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:ctrl.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click="ctrl.setTab(2)" ng-href="/tab/2">Accidents</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

**Template.html**

```
    <div class="template-container">
        <!-- i want the $scope.districts to be changed and the following select show the corresponding options -->
        District:<select ng-model="selectedDistrict" ng-options="item as item for item in districts | orderBy:'toString()' " ></select>
        <!-- A LOT OF SIMILAR CODE WHICH WILL BE USING OTHER UPDATED PARAMETERS -->
    </div>
```

**App.js**

```
  var app= angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
  app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/tab/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'templateController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/tab/1'
      });
  }]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('templateController', function($scope, $routeParams){
   //every time the tab change will cause reload this controller using route provider
   //here you can have tab number in $routeParams.id
   $scope.tabId = $routeParams.id;
   //now you have a tab number you can do use this tab id in your further code execution

   //..other code here..

});
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want the $scope.districts to be changed and the following select
>   show the corresponding option

You could do that in many ways.

Follows a pseudocode as example:

```
$scope.districts = []

$scope.setTab = function(tab) {

    var res = [];

    if (tab == 1) {
        res = $scope.districts.filter(function(item) {
            return item == something;
        });
    }else{
        res = $scope.districts.filter(function(item) {
            return item != something;
        });
    };

    $scope.districts = res;

}
```