# How to do load page in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

How to load content on page by clicking on menu links?
For example, there is menu:

```
<a href="#">Personal</a>
<a href="#">Contacts</a>
```

Question is in how change template HTML in page for each link?

Comment: check out  `ng-view`  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you are trying to achieve will be accomplish by creating SPA. For that you need to use `ngRoute` module in your application(by adding angular-route.js)

For setting up angular router you need to register routes with there template & controller, etc. inside `app.config`.`$routeProvider` would take a URL by `.when` method.

**Code**

```
  var app= angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
  app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/tab/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'templateController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/tab/1'
      });
  }]);
```

& then there would be one section on UI which is nothing but ng-view directive that watches of $routeProvider configuration with url in browser bar

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

For more details look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29984065/2435473)

Working [**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NU2ECRXqSHLtiEIKX3YS?p=preview)

Comment: Can I use `$routeProvider` in separated controller?

Comment: no it doesn;t lie inside a controller, It always be there in application config phase (`app.config`)

Comment: +1 routing is the way. @Hamed check this example i made 4 u - http://plnkr.co/edit/NU2ECRXqSHLtiEIKX3YS?p=preview

Comment: But if I want to use this routing in one controller on my web site? All parts of site was build in php

Comment: @Hamed what do you mean by controller..I didn;t get you..controller is the  part which provides binding for view..you can not relate controller with routing..

Comment: @JossefHarush Thanks man..for your appreciation & help, I'll add this plunkr in answer :)

Comment: I mean that in page there is controller: `EditPageController`, when I click at lick I need load content(template) inside page

Comment: @Hamed ok..then on click you need to change the url in browser url bar..so that angular $routeProvider will load specific template inside the `ng-view` section, you can not have angular route specific to controller, you need to specify different routes for different template..You can have as many number of routes you want.you can have `   $routeProvider

   .when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
     controller: 'mainController'
   })` this sort of route which doesn;t have any thing in url but still loads an template with controller..take a look at attached plunkr

Comment: Can you show example please? How change variable for routing from controller?

Comment: So how to load data in template from AJAX with route way?

Comment: you can get the parameter from url using $routeParms sevice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76764/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-hamed).

Comment: I set link in HTML `<a href="/#test">Moby</a>` but after click page is reflesh, why? Also I need to specify full path to templates? From http://?

Comment: it shouldn't refresh a page in any case..you must be doing something wrong in a code.

Comment: Latest questin. when I click I pass role to controller and after is loaded template. How I can do Ajax in controlelr after click and return data from AJAX in template in route?

Comment: @Hamed discussion is really going out of scope as ypu asked in question..its already solved.please do upvote & accept this answer..And do open another question thanks

Comment: @Hamed please let me know when you added an new question.Thanks :) glad to help you..

Comment: @Hamed I think i gave answer of your question..which you have added recently

Answer (score 0):

Additional to @pankaj, You have to use $location services in your controller. So that you can change view accordingly from controller.

ex. You have link

```
<a ng-click="saveData">Save</a>
```

Now in controller:

```
$scope.saveData = function(){
     $location.href('viewName');
}
```

ref : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location